# Why are certain files not published in the App_Data folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, publish, app-data

I'm using Visual Studion 2008 to build and deploy a webservice project. I've added a bunch of files to the App_Data folder: some xml, some plain text and 2 pdf's. All these files are included in the .csproj file (if they are not, they will  not be published) But when doing a 'publish' from VS2008 (of course with the option 'Included files from the App_Data folder' selected) the pdf's are NOT published. I have tested this with both 'replace' and 'delete' options selected.

Does anyone know why certain files, in this case PDF's, are not published?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the solution explorer right click your pdf's and look at the properties. Change the Build Action from 'None' to 'Content'. The files should now be published with the rest of the project.

Comment: Tested, and confirmed. Thanks!!

Comment: What causes some files to be marked "None" instead of "Content" to begin with?

Comment: PDF files, among other types, are marked 'None' by default when adding them to the solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where CSV files do not publish. Select the file's properties. Change the Build Action from 'None' to 'Content'. Problem solved.